# On Windows with an IIS site what is giving a http error 403

Tags: windows, iis

I am trying to figure out what is giving me a 403 error.
**Details**

- I cannot find the call in the IIS logs.
- Windows Defender Firewall is turned off
- If I run Message Analyzer on the system I can see the call coming in and can see that it is sending out 403.
- If I run Process Monitor I can see that the process "System" does a "TCP Receive" that is probably my call (the number of bytes in it seem to be correct).
- It is an App in IIS off of the Default Website

**How can tell Where it is being given a 403?**
Is there another place to log or another thing I can look at to figure out what is blocking it?

Comment: I don't have a solution, but I found that the URL I am making the request on, is rewritten to another URL, so what I see in the logs is the other URL.  If I could see a log that described that transformation, that would accomplish what I am looking for.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis You should be able to use FRT to check. If FRT shows nothing, then probably something hooking to HTTP.sys returns that 403, and will be difficult to track down.

Answer (score 2):

To figure out the root cause of 403 error, you need to find the sub-status code first. If the request was not logged in IIS log, you could try to force IIS to return detailed error message.

```
<system.webServer>

    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />

</system.webServer>
```

Besides, did you bind host name for your website? If the domain is pointing to the wrong place. Then your IIS would probably not log the request.
Since 403 error is returned from remote server, trace the IIS pipeline with **Failed request tracing** would be more helpful.

In addition, Please ensure application pool identity (IIS Apppool\) and IUSR have read permission to access the root folder of your web application.

Please also remember to check whether unrequired URL rewrite or IP address deny rule was created in Site/Server node.

Finally, remember to clean cache before trying to access the website again.

Comment: That Detailed errorMode seems like it could be quite helpful, I wonder if it would tell me about URL rewrites.  Note that I have solved my problem.  The key was noticing that the URL was being transformed before it hit the IIS logs and I was trying to debug the unmodified endpoint (which was wrong, since it was transformed).  I think I saw the rewritten URL in Process Monitor, but I am not sure what tool it was (I was using so many)

Comment: The failed request tracing log would tell you about URL rewrite as long as it is happening in IIS pipeline.